# Select a row for every date in the table, no matter the data

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following 3 tables in my database:

#### noobs

- id
- name
- img_url
- associations_id

#### noobs_has_points

- noobs_id
- points_id

#### points

- id
- amount
- create_time (as UNIX timestamp)

I want to get a result for every day (such as `FROM_UNIXTIME(points.create_time,'%Y-%m-%d')`). And in that result I want the noobs.id and his amount of points so SUM(points.amount). So whether a noob has actually scored points on that day doesn't matter, if he did not I would want a row with 0 in there as the amount, so that for every day I get to see how many points each noob scored.

However, I have no idea how to get this result. I have tried some things with left/right (or unioned) joins but I don't get the result I want. Can anyone help me with this?

Example results:

```
day        | points.amount | noobs.id
2015-04-11 | 3             | 1
2015-04-11 | 0             | 2 (no points scored, no entry in database)
2015-04-12 | 0             | 1 (no points scored, no entry in database)
2015-04-12 | 1             | 2
```

Some sample data from the three tables:

Noobs

```
id | name | img_url | associations_id
1  | Rien | NULL    | 1
2  | Peter| NULL    | 1
```

noobs_has_points

```
noobs_id | points_id
1        | 1
2        | 3
```

points

```
id | amount | create_time
1  | 3      | 1428779292
2  | 1      | 1428805351
```

Comment: The question is not so clear.. provide some sample data from all the tables.

Comment: I added some sample data now, thanks for looking into it.

Answer (score 1):

Because there may be no dara for a given day for a given noob, you need a way to generate date values. Unfortunately, mysql doesn't have a built-in way to do this. You can code a range into the query with a series if unions as a subquery, but it's ugly and not scalable.

I recommend creating a table to hold date values:

```
create table dates(_date date not null primary key);
```

And populating it with lots of dates (say everything from 1970-2020).

Then you can code:

```
select _date day, sum(p.amount) total, n.id
from dates d
cross join noobs n
left join noobs_has_points np on np.noob_id = n.id
left join points p on p.id = np.points_id
  and date(p.create_time) = _date
where _date between ? and ?
group by 1, 3
```

The cross join gives every noob a result for every date in the specified range, while to left joins ensure a zero for days without points for the noob.